# how to display message in pop box using javascript

Tags: javascript, popup

how to display message value of form message field in pop box in javascript

Comment: Depends on how fancy you want it to be. alert("Message"); is the standard. If you want a more fancy popup, you can try facebox.

Answer (score 5):

without using any frameworks, you can simply use

```
alert('message');
```

or

```
confirm('sure?');
```

or

```
prompt('insert something:');
```

Answer (score 1):

See the jQuery UI
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

To look it professional, fancybox is a option.
Check out http://fancybox.net/